# How to compress video size to desired size using FFMPEG in Android?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I am working on `Android` application where I need to compress video to 80%, 60%, 40% and 25% of actual size. To achieve this I am using [VideoKit](https://github.com/dotintent/videokit-ffmpeg-android) library in my application. I am able to compress video using below command in the library.

```
String command = "-vf scale=960:540 -r 12 -qscale:v 10 -b:v 1762k -acodec copy -b:a 61k";
```

But my requirement is to compress video on the basis of size. For example I am having video of 100MB and I want to compress it to 60% then it should be compressed to size 60MB. Please note I am not concern about the quality of the video. Above command is not working as expected.So I came across [Two-Pass Mechanism](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Two-PassExample) which gives output of required file size. How can I use below command in [VideoKit](https://github.com/dotintent/videokit-ffmpeg-android) library. I tried to use it but it is not working giving an error code as 3018.

```
 ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2600k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 /dev/null && \
 ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 2600k -pass 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

If someone has tried then it will be a great help to me.

Comment: Is ffmpeg actually being executed? If yes, is there any error in its log?

Comment: @llogan Library is is giving error code as 3018, I tried to search this code but library is not having any discription for it.

Comment: Add `-report` option to ffmpeg command and then search for file named something like `ffmpeg-20200719-113931.log`